# After mounting partitions still getting Live CD's files

Tags: mount, livecd

I want to edit my system's `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` file from live CD (guess why...).

I executed the following commands:

```
sudo su
cd /mnt
mkdir os
cd os
mkdir dev sys lib lib64 bin etc proc home boot
mount /dev/sda8 /mnt/os
mount /dev/sda9 /mnt/os/home
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/os/boot
mount --rbind /sys /mnt/os/sys
mount --rbind /proc /mnt/os/proc
mount --rbind /dev /mnt/os/dev
mount --rbind /bin /mnt/os/bin
mount --rbind /lib /mnt/os/lib
mount --rbind /lib64 /mnt/os/lib64
mount --rbind /etc /mnt/os/etc
chroot /mnt/os
```

After that I still get a line `root@kubuntu:/#`. I thought that it would change `kubuntu` to my computer name or something different. But I am on my computer because when I `cd /mnt` I don't have `os` directory but others. `/home` is also properly mounted - I can see all my files.
So, after I go to `/etc/pam.d` and I `cat common-auth` I don't see my computer's file but Kubuntu's.
Why did I do wrong?

BTW, when I `cat` the file before chroot it's the same than after `chroot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong in your procedure:

1. You don't need to recreate any folders in `/mnt/os` with mkdir. Once you mount disk on a folder, everything inside the original folder gets temporarily hidden and replaced by content of the mounted disk. Your `/dev/sda8` most likely already contains these folders - and if not, they won't be created this way.
2. Same applies to mount-bind. You cannot edit PAM configuration on your `/dev/sda` drive because you replace the `/etc` folder from your disk with the one on live cd before you call chroot.
3. Futhermore you don't need to bind anything except `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys` into your chroot environment. These folders contain abstract files that represent devices and parts of operating system. They are generated by your kernel at boot or runtime and need to be available inside the chrooted environment otherwise some of the programs might not work. If you don't mount these folders, they will appear empty on your `/dev/sda8` when viewed from live cd. You can find quick summary of what each folder in Unix filesystem is supposed to contain on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_filesystem#Conventional_directory_layout).
4. The only reason why you'd need to bind `/bin` or `/lib` would be if architecture or kernel of system on live cd was incompatible with filesystem on your harddisk. But in that case it wouldn't be a good idea to chroot like this - it brings no benefits.

Finally, if you're only editing configuration files, you don't need to chroot into your drive. You can just mount the root partition and directly edit the file from live cd system with pre-installed editor like `nano`:

```
mount /dev/sda8 /mnt
nano /mnt/etc/pam.d/common-auth
```